# As sort an array of numbers in ascending order

Tags: arrays, vba, visual-studio, sorting, random

I have a code to display a non-repeating random numbers, but I stuck by not sort in ascending order.

Here my code:

```
    Public Class Form1
        Dim intNumber As Integer
        Dim arrNumber(0 To 5) As Integer
        Dim i, x, y As Integer
        Private Sub mostrar_resultados_sorteo(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
            repetido()
            For i = 0 To 5
                ListBox1.Items.Add(arrNumber(i).ToString)           
            Next
        End Sub            
        Private Sub repetido()
            For x = 0 To 5
    Start:
                Randomize()
                intNumber = Int((49 * Rnd()) + 1)
                For y = 0 To 5

                    If intNumber = arrNumber(y) Then
                        GoTo Start
                    End If                         
 Next y
        arrNumber(x) = intNumber
    Next x
    ordenar()
End Sub
Private Sub ordenar()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Is your ListBox1 set to sort items?

Comment: listbox is only for printing, the numbers have to go out and sorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not tagged with programming language, but I guess it is VB.

Please see [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zfce6bw8.aspx) on how to sort an array.

Comment: Thanks, works perfect, could not find the proper documentation